# Compare node and query selector

Tags: javascript

I want to check equal to js node object and query selector str.

Ex:

```js
const node = document.querySelector('#id');// or .className or [atrribute] or 'ul > li.span'
const checkQuerySelector= '[attribute=value]';

if(node.isEqual(checkQuerySelector)){
  //.vs
}

//Jquery example
$('<div id="test"></div>').is('#id');
```

i don't write isEqual func.
I know with jquery but i want to find/write with core JavaScript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches

Comment: Tip: You can always read the jQuery source to find out what it does.

Comment: @tadman, I read but I couldn't grasp it. thanks, i will test. @`Yury Tarabanko` Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: No shame in admitting that, as jQuery can be quite complicated. That's part of the reason why people use it: You won't have to tackle that complexity yourself.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes, thanks.